# Run spring boot application locally in windows with other services run on docker compose network

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose

I'm running a spring boot application locally in windows(intelliJ Idea) with other applications which connect to it run on containers run using docker compose(one network). But the docker services cannot access or hit calls for the locally running app. Any advice on how to do that is appreciated.

docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app1-db:
    image: postgres:15.1
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "app1-db"
      POSTGRES_USER: "app1-db"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "app1-db_password"
        
  app1:
    image: {image from remote repo}
    depends_on:
      - "app1-db"
    links:
      - "app1-db"
    environment:
      APP1_DB_JDBC_DRIVER: "org.postgresql.Driver"
      APP1_DB_JDBC_DATASOURCE_URL: "jdbc:postgresql://app1-db:5432/app1"
      APP1_DB_USERNAME: "app1-db"
      APP1_DB_PASSWORD: "app1-db_password"
      APP1_POSTGRES_ENABLED: "true"
      LOCALLY_RUNNING_APP_BASE_URL: "http://172.17.0.1:25011"

  app2-db:
    image: postgres:15.1
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "app2-db"
      POSTGRES_USER: "localuser123"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "121212"

  app2:
    image: {image from remote repo}
    depends_on:
      app2-db:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: "local"
      SERVER_PORT: "8082"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: "jdbc:postgresql://app2-db:5432/app2-db"
```

docker-compose.abc.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:

  app1-db:
    networks:
      - integration-test-network

  app1:
    profiles: []
    networks:
      - integration-test-network

  app2-db:
    networks:
      - integration-test-network

  app2:
    networks:
      - integration-test-network
networks:
  integration-test-network:
    name: "network_abc"
```

docker-compose.override.yml

version: "3.9"

```
services:

  app1-db:
    ports:
      - "5502:5432"

  app1:
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "5002:5002"

  app2-db:
    ports:
      - "5503:5432"

  app2:
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
      - "5003:5003"
```

I'm building and running the above with **docker-compose up -d**

Comment: Please share your docker-compose file

Comment: @AndreyGrigoriev, I've added the docker-compose file as an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix the problem by adding "extra_hosts" as the following in docker-compose.yml;

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app1-db:
    image: postgres:15.1
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "app1-db"
      POSTGRES_USER: "app1-db"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "app1-db_password"
        
  app1:
    image: {image from remote repo}
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    depends_on:
      - "app1-db"
    links:
      - "app1-db"
    environment:
      APP1_DB_JDBC_DRIVER: "org.postgresql.Driver"
      APP1_DB_JDBC_DATASOURCE_URL: "jdbc:postgresql://app1-db:5432/app1"
      APP1_DB_USERNAME: "app1-db"
      APP1_DB_PASSWORD: "app1-db_password"
      APP1_POSTGRES_ENABLED: "true"
      LOCALLY_RUNNING_APP_BASE_URL: "http://host.docker.internal:25011"
...
```

and changing the LOCALLY_RUNNING_APP_BASE_URLto have **host.docker.internal** instead of just the static ip **172.17.0.1**

This article helped me: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host

Answer (score 0):

Use **ports** section (see the documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#ports)) of docker-compose file to expose a service port to your host OS. See the example (I showed it only for postgres service, but you would need to specify it in each service you want to expose):

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app1-db:
    image: postgres:15.1
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "app1-db"
      POSTGRES_USER: "app1-db"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "app1-db_pass"
```

Comment: But I've forgotton to mention that I have the ports for the services defined in my docker-compose.override.yml

Comment: And you cannot connect to any of the services, even to postgres on port 5502?

Comment: many thanks for the help! I've found the problem:) It was just that the container could not call API in the app running in Windows host because it was not able to bind to 172.17.0.1